# I am creating a virtual voice assistant, everything is fine but the time taken to execute the command is way too much. So can I reduce the time taken

Tags: python

I took guidance from geeksforgeeks site. Everything seems fine but the time taken between the'Listening.....' and 'Recognising......' is way too much. So is there a way by which i can reduce theamount of time taken to execute the task. I have used the pyttsx3 module and Speech_recognition module.  Here's my code (please help I'm a bit new to python):

```
    engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)

    def speak(audio):
        engine.say(audio)
        engine.runAndWait()
    
    def wishMe():
        hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
        if hour>= 0 and hour<12:
            speak("Good Morning Mister Stark !")
    
        elif hour>= 12 and hour<17:
            speak("Good Afternoon Mister Stark !")  
    
        if hour >17 and hour <22:
            speak("Good Evening Mister Stark !")

        else:
            speak("You should be asleep Mister Stark, but")

        speak("How may i help you?")


    def takeCommand():
        
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            
            print("Listening...")
            r.pause_threshold = 1
            r.energy_threshold = 300
            audio = r.listen(source)
        
        try:
            print("Recognizing...")   
            query = r.recognize_google(audio, language ='en-in')
            print(f"User said: {query}\n")
    
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)   
            print("Unable to Recognize your voice.") 
            return "None"
        
        return query



    if __name__ == '__main__':
    # clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
        
        # This Function will clean any
        # command before execution of this python file
        #clear()
        wishMe()
        
        while True:
            
            query = takeCommand().lower()
            
            # All the commands said by user will be
            # stored here in 'query' and will be
            # converted to lower case for easily
            # recognition of command
            if 'wikipedia' in query:
                speak('Searching Wikipedia...')
                query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
                results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences = 3)
                speak("According to Wikipedia")
                print(results)
                speak(results)
                continue 
    
            elif 'open youtube' in query:
                speak("Here you go to Youtube\n")
                webbrowser.open("www.youtube.com")
                continue
    
            elif 'open google' in query:
                speak("Here you go to Google\n")
                webbrowser.open("www.google.com")
                continue

            elif 'the time' in query:
                strTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("% H:% M:% S")   
                speak(f"Sir, the time is {strTime}")
                continue
```

Comment: Have you tried reducing `pause_threshold`?

Comment: @RandomDavis [the docs](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#recognizer_instancepause_threshold--08---type-float) say that is just the threshold to cut between sentences, so it is not that.

Answer (score 0):

The docs (for the latest version as of today : 3.8.1) say about [`recognizer_instance.listen`](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/3.8.1/reference/library-reference.rst#recognizer_instancelistensource-audiosource-timeout-unionfloat-none--none-phrase_time_limit-unionfloat-none--none-snowboy_configuration-uniontuplestr-iterablestr-none--none---audiodata) :

> This operation will always complete within `timeout + phrase_timeout` seconds if both are numbers, either by returning the audio data, or by raising a `speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError` exception.
> [...]
> The `timeout` parameter is the maximum number of seconds that this will wait for a phrase to start before giving up and throwing an `speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError` exception. If `timeout` is `None`, there will be no wait timeout.
> [...]
> The `phrase_time_limit` parameter is the maximum number of seconds that this will allow a phrase to continue before stopping and returning the part of the phrase processed before the time limit was reached. The resulting audio will be the phrase cut off at the time limit. If `phrase_timeout` is `None`, there will be no phrase time limit.

Your code specifies neither of both timeouts, so that the listening may take arbitrary long.
Fiddle with one (or both) timeout to find a working value.